# How to handle improper input files

Tags: c++, exception

I am starting a project and I am wondering on best practices for handling errors during file input handling.  My current plan for the project involves a process in `main` along the lines of:

```
unique_ptr<Configuration> config(initConfig(argc,argv));
unique_ptr<InterfaceA> a(initA(config));

// Do real work here
```

The initialization data for the Configuration class and all other classes will be contained in a header for their input files such as:

```
#ObjectA-1
```

The `ObjectA` tells me I have a file meant to be turned into an object that fulfills `InterfaceA`, and the `1` tells me which specific implementation of that interface to use.

My question is in error handling for functions such as `initConfig` and `initA`.  Inside of those functions I will parse the first line of their respective files, and decode the above information.  If, let's say, in `initA` I happen to get a file that does not have the appropriate header, be it `#ObjectB-3`, or no header at all.  I see two ways to go about handling the error:

- Throw an exception that will be caught in main.  This will allow me to print an error, then bypass other init functions via an error flag, and do any high level clean up I need to.  The bad part of this is that my `main` is them mostly made of exception handling, which makes the code much harder to read.
- Print an error from inside the init function, then call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` and lean on my OS to do the cleanup of the previously allocated memory.  This would likely lead to cleaner code and more local error handling.

I personally would prefer the second if it wasn't for the use of the `exit` function.

Comment: Since you're using C++, is there a reason you're not using RAII?

Comment: Honestly, I'd have written all of those lines as just `Configuration config(argc, argv); InterfaceA a(config);`. No memory management necessary.

Comment: the issue is that I need logic to figure out which type of `A` to create.

Comment: @GodricSeer Oh okay, then `Configuration config(argc, argv); shared_ptr<InterfaceA> a(InterfaceA::fromConfig(config));`.

Comment: @sftrabbit I understand that using the shared_ptr would eliminate my memory management, however I don't understand the `a(InterfaceA::fromConfig(config))`.  InterfaceA has purely virtual methods, so I can't have a constructor of it in that way.

Comment: @GodricSeer I'm pretending that there's a static function called `fromConfig`, really just the same as your `initA` function.

Comment: @sftrabbit I understand now.  I was thinking `a()` was calling a constructor for the interface, not the constructor to the shared_ptr.  So I simply need to return a shared_ptr (or standard pointer) from the `fromConfig` function?

Comment: I don't know why I said `shared_ptr`. I would get it to return a `unique_ptr` and have code that looks like this: `Configuration config(argc, argv); unique_ptr<InterfaceA> a = InterfaceA::fromConfig(config);`. Sorry I haven't answered the question about error handling yet.

Comment: @sftrabbit I have updated the psuedo-code to reflect your advice, along with my worries in error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following rules to perform error handling:

1. Is it an exceptional occurrence that the calling code should handle if it can? If so, throw an exception. Sometimes "exceptional" is hard to define, so think about it more like "should this ever happen?" I think in this case you should be throwing exceptions and `main` should be handling them *if* it makes sense to.

   There are two groups of exceptions defined by the standard. First there's those that inherit from `std::logic_error`. These are usually thrown when the calling code has broken your function's contract. Then there's those that inherit from `std::runtime_error`, which are used for errors that can only be detected at run-time. This sounds exactly like yours. It only knows that there is a problem with the file when it reads it.

   Of course, you can throw your own exception types if you like.
2. Is it an error which is considered normal and may be ignored by the calling code? This might be an appropriate use of error codes.
3. Is it a logical error internal to your code? This makes more sense as an `assert`. You should use `assert`s to verify that what you're doing actually makes sense. A stupid example would be `int y = 5; y++; assert(y == 6);`. Think of it as insurance against stupid mistakes.

So as I've said, your problem sounds like a good place to use exceptions. There should be absolutely no issues with memory allocation if you use RAII correctly. That is, all memory deallocation should be done in the destruction of objects. Destructors are still called even when exceptions are thrown.